# BizTalk WCF and Soap Action

Tags: wcf, biztalk

i'm calling a WCF service using BizTalk 2009 as intermediate endpoint, now i changed the wsdl of the service being called by biztalk (i changed the soap action attributes in the wsdl's binding section), now when i call the service via-biz talk exposed WS it inform's me about an interface mismatch (regarding the Action attribute), how can i solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have an orchestration in BizTalk 2009 that is exposed to clients as a WCF service. This same orchestration is consuming another Web Service to perform its duty. Now, you manually changed the WSDL of the consumed web service ? In that case, you need to update the web service reference in your orchestration and recompile. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you've just changed the SOAP Action, then you can change this in BizTalk on the send port (Admin Console, Right Click on the Port, Configure, and change the Action under the General tab at the bottom). But if you've changed schemas, added new operations etc, you should regenerate everthing again as per Maxine's comment.